# What does a squared coefficient of variation signify?

Tags: variance, mean, standard-deviation, coefficient-of-variation

The coefficient of variation is defined as the ratio of S.D to mean, a dimensionless number which on multiplication by 100 gives the percentage of dispersion with mean. But when we square this coefficient of variation, what does it signify?

(I have to understand a graph having squared coefficient of variation on y axis and mean on x axis for Poisson distributed data).

Thanks

Comment: The coefficient of variation is $\frac{\text{sd}(X)}{\text{mean}(X)}$. This is the same as $\text{sd}(\frac{X}{\text{mean}(X)})$. If you square this you just get the variance of $\frac{X}{\text{mean}(X)}$, i.e. X expressed in units of $\text{mean}(X)$. Does this help you?

Comment: I am just a beginner... I want to confirm my basic understanding (1) suppose i have four numbers i.e 5,7,9,11 (2) mean of these numbers comes out to be 8 (3) variance calculated as (8-5)^2 + (8-7)^2 + (8-9)^2 + (9-11)^ / 4 = 5 and the S.D is underroot of 5 i.e 2.23 (5) the coefficient of variation : 2.23/mean(=8) will be .2795 (6) if i square .2795 , i get ~ .078 ... so how to comprehend this .078 in terms of my data (5,7,9,11) ?

Comment: Are you sure this is a squared CV and not the ratio of the sample variance to the sample mean?  For a Poisson distribution, this ratio should be close to 1, so it could make sense to plot it against the mean as a check for departures from "Poissonness": the plot should be approximately level.  Plotting the squared CV would instead produce a hyperbolic curve, which is not a good visual reference for exploring and understanding data.

Comment: This is not an answer but I am not allowed to comment yet. I am also perplexed by the widespread use of this metric in bioinformatics. This recent paper is one of many which uses it to visualize technical noise.... ??? http://www.nature.com/nrg/journal/v16/n3/fig_tab/nrg3833_F2.html

Comment: @whuber may I ask why you used SCV instead of CV in the DESeq paper?

Comment: I can't post this as a comment as I don't have a high enough reputation yet, but in reply to @gkcn, I believe this is a different W Huber. whuber is a William, and the DESeq author is a Wolfgang.